# EWS: Too many open sessions/logons - How to close?

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server

I am developing a indexing service for Exchange servers using EWS. I also use impersonalisation to read the accounts of all my users. Recently I was monitoring a server with a tool called "OpManager". It threw an error message: "Active client logons is 5300 Logons, threshold value for this monitor is 5000 Logons". 
I use the new ExchangeService() constructor extensively and then I impersonalize this instances but I have no knowledge of any close- or logoff- methods in the EWS API. Any idea how to release or reduce these logons?

BTW: I even don't know if this error message has any negative effects but my client wishes to clear the case.

Thanks you for any hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key of impersonation is to have one impersonation account which has access to different users. I don't think it is smart to keep your connection opened. I created a service too which monitor different users. I use a timer. When i pull for requests i set the impersonation for the current user, and when i am ready i remove the impersonation link (set to null). So make one instance which login as impersonate user, then set impersonation based on the user.